# Maven or Not to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I've been a programmer for 23 years. I am doing Java, Spring and using Eclipse as my IDE.  Most of my projects are web based that run in Tomcat and JBoss. The firm I am in now is requesting that I look at Maven for my projects but I see Maven as a build tool...  We are using Subversion for version control etc., but how does Maven fit in? And where do I start?

We are using the following

Java,Spring, JBoss, Eclipse, Subversion

Please give me some input.

Comment: The question has been closed so I can't answer, but I'll comment: I think you should consider any tools that might help, but in my experience Maven is a lot of trouble, way more trouble than it's worth for many projects. A lot of people promote it as the cure for all your ailments, but it can be a real pain the rear and isn't justified for all projects (that's true for any tool, of course). I encourage you to not just read the hype; look for blogs and stories about the difficulties with Maven and carefully consider the impact of using something that tries to be excessively "automatic."

Comment: Maven is mainly a dependency manager, dependencies of your project and dependencies of your project dependencies and so on. You can go without it but then you have to do it manually. It's value is comparable to Eclipse or svn or git and currently it is defacto as dependency manager and public Maven repositories are defacto for jar file distribution.

Answer (score 5):

definitely go for Maven. it really put order in the build process and has some cool features as automatic dependency management.

it also contains plugins that integrate well with all the tools you mentioned.

start at http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/ for a Maven book

Answer (score 4):

Maven is a build/deploy tool. It is similar in use to **cmake** or **ant**. It can be plugged in eclipse via plugins, it can be used to deploy wars/jars to tomcat/jboss/websphere etc. It can run test suites and many more.

You should take a look at Maven In 5 Minutes.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins, maven and subversion are a great team. Once you have everything configured, jenkins you can relax and watch jenkins checking out the sources from your subversion repositories and have maven building your application.

You can watch him working or enjoy the build reports after the work is done.

Thumbs up for maven and [hire the butler](http://jenkins-ci.org/)!

Comment: We were using ant scripts. This combination greatly improved our life (though Maven has a pretty steep learning curve). In addition, throw a Maven repository in there, like Nexus, then: you commit a change and a minute later you new snapshot is available in your maven repo for other developers to test. Magic

Answer (score 3):

Defnitely maven.  IDE is not a build system  and is not suitable for dependency management.  With maven you can specify build wchich works almost everywhere and is predictable.  Another advantage is dependency specification - ypu just say that you need spring in version x.y.z and hibernate in version z.k.y and you just get it with all dependencies.

Use maven as primary build tool, and generate eclipse project files out of it.  (and never checkin .project or .classpath into source control ). And some IDEs (notably: idea ) just use maven build descriptors as project.

You will also get a lot of advnates from maevn - release process, documentation website  generation etc.